# License issue when USB-LAN stick is connected.

Tags: licensing

I have mathematica installed on my laptop which only have a wifi card. When I connect a USB-LAN adapter, even if it is not connected to the LAN socket, mathematica complains that the license is invalid. Is there a way to configure mathematica to ignore the LAN adapter?

The laptop runs a Linux Mint 17.3

Comment: It sounds like it would be a good idea to contact Wolfram Support about this, http://support.wolfram.com/

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to ask for another license password directly from Wolfram. Otherwise you might try to change the MAC address of the USB-LAN adapter to exactly the same one of the wifi card. Of course then you cannot use Wifi card and USB-LAN simulaneously (since no two MAC addresses should be identical on the same subnet), but the license should now.

Comment: The problem with asking for another license password is that I'm not always taking the USB-LAB adapter with me...